# Avoid default today's date in Jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an old project, they are using a jquery datepicker and we want to get rid of the default toda's date that appears in the input.

Here is the html tags:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"\" id=\"pick_some_deadline_at\" class=\"date text \" data-date-with-hiddens=\"trigger\" autocomplete=\"off\" data-validate=\"\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"some\" id=\"some_1i_\" value=\"\" data-date-with-hiddens=\"year\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"some\" id=\"some_2i_\" value=\"\" data-date-with-hiddens=\"month\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"some\" id=\"some_3i\" value=\"\" data-date-with-hiddens=\"day\" />
```

As you can see in the html tags, there are no values. But, we see the today's date in the browser input.

1) Is this datepicker coming from `gem gem 'jquery-rails' # needed by remotipart`
2) How can it be possible that we see the today's date in the input, but the values in the dom inputs are not set.

I would like some help on understanding how this jquery datepickers work, so that I can avoid having the today's date in the input

Comment: Use the [`defaultDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) setting in the properties of the DatePicker

Comment: You mean in the gem source code? so you confirmed that this is the expected behaviour, if no value is passed, the today's date is placed, but the input values are not updated in rails. But if we change the defaultDate, then it's change for all the datepickers, and we just want it for one

Comment: No, I mean set it in your JS code where you instantiate the datepicker. This has nothing to do with Rails.